# How to pass version range externally in gradle

Tags: gradle, versioning

Gradle (version 2.11) novice trying to figure how to define version range outside build.gradle.

```
List artifactIds_group1=[
    'g1_a1',
    'g1_a2',
    'g1_a3'
]
def group1_deps=[]
artifactIds_group1.each {
    group1_deps.push(
        [
            group: 'com.example.group1',
            name: "$it",
            version: '(,2016.02.24-UTC]'
        ]
    )
}
```

I have multiple such groupIds+artifactIds and wanted to pass version range cap (always follows format `yyyy.mm.dd-UTC` - where `-UTC` is hardcoded) via

1. gradle.properties
2. command line (`-Pmy_version=2016.02.24-UTC`)

Dependencies are hosted on a maven repo in artifactory by another team. So I tried all of these in vain:

1. build.gradle with `version: "$my_version"` and gradle.properties with `my_version='(,2016.02.24-UTC]'`
2. build.gradle with `version: "(,$my_version]"` and gradle.properties with `my_version='2016.02.24-UTC'`
3. build.gradle with `version: "(," + my_version + "]"` and gradle.properties with `my_version='2016.02.24-UTC'`

I might have gotten that last one wrong (not sure about `project.` and `project.ext` prefixes).

However, it seems that unless defined inside build.gradle, type of input is string (not version spec).

Can someone please share how to control that range cap externally ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties in the gradle.properties file like so:

```
def my_version = project.ext['my_version']
```

You can access a command line var like so:

```
gradle(w) (task) -Pmy_version=2016.02.24-UTC
def my_version = project.hasProperty('my_version') ? project.my_version : "not found"
```